# Optimize SQL to fetch 1 day data

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I need to fetch last 24 hrs data frequently and this query runs frequently.
Since this scans many rows, using it frequently, affects the database performance.

MySql execution strategy picks index on created_at and that returns 1,00,000 rows approx. and these rows are scanned one by one to filter customer_id = 10 and my final result has 20000 rows.

How can I optimize this query?

```
explain SELECT  *
FROM    `order`
WHERE    customer_id = 10
and `created_at` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;

id : 1
select_type : SIMPLE
table : order
partitions : NULL
type : range
possible_keys : idx_customer_id, idx_order_created_at
key : idx_order_created_at
key_len : 5
ref : NULL
rows : 103357
filtered : 1.22
Extra : Using index condition; Using where
```

Comment: You are selecting `*`. Do you really need all the columns?

Comment: no, original query don't have * in it

Answer (score 1):

Instead of two single indexes on ID and Created, create a single composite index on ( customer_id, created_at ).   This way the index engine can use BOTH parts of the where clause instead of just hoping to get the one.  Jump right to the customer ID, then jump directly to the date desired, then gives results.  it SHOULD be very fast.

Additional Follow-up.
I hear your comment about having multiple indexes, but add those into the main one, just after such as

( customer_id, created_at, updated_at, completion_time )

Then, in your queries could always include some help on the index in the where clause.  For example, and I don't know your specific data.  A record is created at some given point.  The updated and completion time will always be AFTER that.  How long does it take (worst-case scenario) from a creation to completion time... 2 days, 10 days, 90 days?

```
where
       customerID = ?
   AND created_at >= date - 10 days
   AND updated_at >= date -1
```

Again, just an example, but if a person has 1000's of orders and relatively quick turn-around time, you could jump to those most recent and then find those updated within the time period..  Again, just an option as a single index vs 3, 4 or more indexes.

Comment: It would only help if one/both columns had high cardinality.

Comment: yup, thought of doing the same, but there are other date columns on the table, like updated_at, completion_time and few more... and other queries make use f those columns with customer_id. In case if we decided to use composite indexes, we need to create index like (customer_id, created_at), (customer_id, updated_at), (customer_id, completion_time), this will affect the insertion time of the query

Comment: `date - 1` does not work for the first of the month.

Answer (score 1):

The first optimization I would do is on the access to the table:

```
create index ix1 on `order` (customer_id, created_at);
```

Then, if the query is still slow I would try appending the columns you are selecting to the index. If, for example, you are selecting the columns `order_id`, `amount`, and `status`:

```
create index ix1 on `order` (customer_id, created_at, 
  order_id, amount, status);
```

This second strategy could be beneficial, but you'll need to test it to find out what performance improvement it peoduces in your particular case.

The big improvement of this second strategy is that it walks the secondary index only, by avoiding to walk back to the primary clustered index of the table (that can be time consumming).

Comment: Why would appending columns appearing only in the select clause have any impact?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Edited accordingly.

Comment: yup, thought of doing the same, but there are other date columns on the table, like updated_at, completion_time and few more... and other queries make use f those columns with customer_id. In case if we decided to use composite indexes, we need to create index like (customer_id, created_at), (customer_id, updated_at), (customer_id, completion_time), this will affect the insertion time of the query

Comment: Yes, it will affect the inserts, deletes, and updates on the table. You need to be careful on how many indexes you add to the table. My [very] personal rule of thumb is to limit the number of indexes to a maximum of 10.

Comment: I don't think your second strategy is an improvement. You are just trying to achieve covering index, but at the end you may duplicate the whole clustered index multiple times. Considering this is an frequent task, it's not an solution.

Comment: Can I create database partitions, and run query this query? just a thought.... What is better strategy to create partition in this case? partition based on date?

Comment: Rule of Thumb:  Don't have more than 5 columns in an index.

Comment: @prranay - In this example, the composite index will be _at least as fast_ as _any_ kind of `PARTITIONing`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are dealing a very quick growing table, I should consider moving this frequent query to a cold table or replica.

One more point is that did you consider partition by customer_id. I am not quite understand the business logic behind to query customer_id = 10. If it's multi tenancy application, try partition.

Comment: yeah, so my doubt is, if I created the partition on customer_id, how mysql will create execution strategy? Will scan only rows that matched date or will it scan all rows and filter based on date? considering i already have index on created_at column

Comment: Partitioning applies to all data and indexes of a table. So MySQL will scan the created_at index for this partition.

Comment: To clarify, it won't scan all rows because created_at index will be used.

Comment: If you do `PARTITION BY RANGE(customer_id)`, do _not_ (as a general rule) put that column first in any index.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM `order` o
WHERE o.customer_id = 10 AND
      created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

My first inclination would be a composite index on `(customer_id, created_at)` -- as others have suggested.

But, you appear to have a lot of data and many inserts per day.  That suggests partitioning plus an index.  The appropriate partition would be on `created_at`, probably on a daily basis, along with an index for `user_id`.

A typical query would access the two most recent partitions.  Because your queries are focused on recent data, this also reduces the memory occupied by the index, which might be an overall benefit.

Comment: if we consider to use partitioning, what will be the better strategy for the same? do I create partition based on customer_id or based on created_at? Creating partition based on date will solve the problem for data that is recently used and falls into last 1 or 2 partitions, but how mysql will behave if someday i need to make query for data analytics that uses 20-30 partitions?
such query will not be used frequently and we can take performance hit for some time, my only concern is, performance hit should be as low as possible

Comment: How database will behave if my number of partitions are more?

Comment: @prranay . . . Typically, you would create the partitions by time, on `created_at`.  Presumably, you are looking at different users in queries, rather than different time frames.  If so, then only one or two partitions are loaded into memory.

Answer (score 0):

This technique should be better than all the other answers, though perhaps by only a small amount:

Instead of `orders` being indexed thus:

```
PRIMARY KEY(order_id)   -- AUTO_INCREMENT
INDEX(customer_id, ...)  -- created_at, and possibly others
```

do this to "cluster" the rows together:

```
PRIMARY KEY(customer_id, order_id)
INDEX (order_id)   -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

Then you can optionally have more indexes starting with `customer_id` as needed.  Or not.

Another issue -- What will you do with 20K rows?  That is a lot to feed to a client, especially of the human type.  If you then munch on it, can't you make a more complex query that does more work, and returns fewer rows?  *That* will probably be faster.